# How to replace a character by a line break in VS or SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, ssms

How to replace a character (or many characters) by a line break in VS or SQL Server Management Studio using the Find and Replace dialog?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

At the bottom of the "Find and Replace" dialog, check the box "Use" and select "Regular expressions"

Then in the "Replace with" box put `\n`

Answer (score 7):

You can do a regular expression find and replace on `\x0d\x0a`, which represents a line break.